# Glassfish is hanging forever on deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee

My glassfish has problem, when I run a webapp it starts but it hangs forever at the level of deployment.

output:

deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Caleb\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AutoQcm_ENG2\build\web

It hangs there forever and ever.

At first it was deploying properly but now it is not. I don't know what is wrong.

I am using:
 1. Netbeans7.3
 2. Glassfish 3.1.2.1

I searched extensively on stackoverflow and on the internet and tried some of the solutions. For the example:

1. replacing the weld-integration jar
2. Another one was unchecking the Use IDE's proxy settings in netbeans.

But non of them worked

I even downloaded glassfish4 and tried to deploy the app with it, but it still hangs
I have tried to deploy other applications which where deploying formerly but it still hangs.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled netbeans but the problem still persists

I am very new to Glassfish and the JEE platform,so let the answers be explicit and simple for me to understand Please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

1. check from the web console if any applications are still deployed and frist undeploy them
2. stop your server/domain
3. empty the domain[x]/autodeploy/ folder
4. empty the domain[x]/osgi-cache/ folder
5. restart your server/domain and see if your deployment now works.